# Visual Studio 2008 issue publishing C# desktop applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have been publishing C# application using Visual Studio 2008 for some years now to a shared directory on a server so that our users can easily install the applications and the app can check for updates I have made easily.

In the past all I had to do was give the user a direct link to the setup.exe file. After one of the Microsoft updates in the past week I can no longer do that. I'm not sure what update did it since the environment I work in updates are pushed to machine from corporate division that oversees more that 100,000 machines.

Anyway, now clicking on the setup.exe produces what you see in the image at this URL

[image]

Also the date on setup.exe is always 7/29/2008, but the rest of the files have the correct date. I've also noticed that if the publish.htm file is created everything works if it is used through IE to install the app. I'm wondering if anyone has seen this or has a clue why this is happening all of a sudden.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the mechanism that you use to create this setup. Also, I'm not sure if this question belongs to SO or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: I just use the built in Publish Wizard in Visual Studio 2008. On the Publish Tab under the Solution Properties, I have tried every combination in the Option, I have check every combination I can for the deployment.

Comment: Ok, you're using click once, you can check the log in the Event Viewer under the Application section, put it here and let's see

Comment: I cleared the log then ran it again, nothing shows in the logs.

Comment: Did the clients change (e.g., different .NET service pack) in any way?